# Online PIE GRAPH tool with fixed and variable inputs

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, data

I have the following problem, let's assume I have these variables:

A
B
C
D = (G + H + I)
E = (L + M + N + O)
F

BUT WHERE N = 50% of O and L = 3% of N

and A + B + C + D + E + F = TOT

I would like an interactive online graph tool that could help me to fix some of these and fastly change the others, or if I modify the total, have all of them changed accordingly scaled up or diminished keeping the relative % but scaling the value.

eg. let's assign a scalar value like A = 5, B = 7%, and a tot of 100 the system will show something like C+D+E+F = 88, but if I pick also M = 9, it will say C+D+F+L+N+O = 79, then if I will change the TOT actually from 100 to 120, A will stay stable to 5 but B being 7% will not be 7 anymore but will increase accordingly.

I'm up to write a mathematica script in order to do that, but I'm pretty sure someone wrote already a graph tool for it that could be lot more interactive than what I could do for mathematica by myself ^^

If you are wondering what it could be about, it could be very useful if you have to estimate for example a product cost while considering lot of other input variables that could be fixed costs or instead something else that could changes related to the % with the final TOT.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the ["Solver"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) feature in Excel, or Libreoffice. With the Solver you can set objective functions and constraints and find solutions.

Interactivity  could be achieved by putting  slider components on the spreadsheet which are coupled to your inputs.